# Docker build fails to find G++, manually running the step works

Tags: docker, g++, protocol-buffers

My image is attempting to build [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md) 3.9.1 from source on a centos7 base. After updating and installing dependencies, the first step is to run a `./configure` script from the protobuf repo. This goes through and finds a bunch of dependencies required for the build.

The `docker build` fails on `RUN ./configure` with the cause being `checking for g++... no`. When manually running the script by doing a `docker run` into the layer directly before the failed step, `./configure` is able to find g++: `checking for g++... g++`.

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this different behaviour, between `docker build` and manually running the steps? Thanks for reading!

Docker file:

```
FROM centos:7

ENV PROJECTDIR=/src
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECTDIR
WORKDIR $PROJECTDIR

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum install -y epel-release centos-release-scl
RUN yum install -y cmake3 devtoolset-7-gcc* devtoolset-7-gdb* llvm-toolset-7-llvm-devel llvm-toolset-7-clang-devel llvm-toolset-7-lldb make boost169-devel boost169-static openssh-server rsync git ccache autoconf automake libtool unzip tree

RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "path = /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7/root/usr/bin" > /etc/ccache.conf
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/g++
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/x86_64-redhat-linux-c++
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/clang
RUN ln -sf ../../bin/ccache /usr/lib64/ccache/clang++
RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen

# Protobuf C++ Install
RUN mkdir $PROJECTDIR/protobuf
ADD https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.9.1/protobuf-cpp-3.9.1.tar.gz $PROJECTDIR/protobuf/protobuf-cpp-3.9.1.tar.gz
RUN tar -xf $PROJECTDIR/protobuf/protobuf-cpp-3.9.1.tar.gz -C $PROJECTDIR/protobuf/
WORKDIR $PROJECTDIR/protobuf/protobuf-3.9.1

RUN ./configure
    make && \
    make check && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh

ENV PATH="$PROJECTDIR:${PATH}"

CMD bash
```

edit:

I've tried the docker build with and without `cacche` with no affect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/), so it should be installed as a dependency.

> If you are trying to build using make, ensure you've installed the gcc-g++
>   package! Without it, your build will fail in the way you are seeing.

Install `gcc-c++` before configure

`RUN yum install gcc-c++ -y`

Also, correct your configure command it missing `&& \`

```
RUN yum install gcc-c++ -y
RUN ./configure && \
    make && \
    make check && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue for `./configure` but I'm not really sure why. I was installing gcc-c++ via `devtoolset-7-gcc*` which is how I was able to perform the steps manualy. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Yes it is not expected but I face these issue with `devtoolset`. you read here https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/. pls accept the answer if it solve the problem.